# How to Detect, Measures & Debug Javascript strain on CPU?

Tags: javascript, performance

This question is pretty simple:

How does one go about detecting and debugging javascript stress on the CPU and/or optimize the code?

As you start building more and more code you reach points where things slow down. How do you figure out if you have unnecessary js running, maybe redundant code, OR if it's getting too much for a computer? My computer is pretty powerful but I can't assume everyone has a monster computer.

Is there a function, program or some tools that can help with this task?

This question seems general but I really don't know how to simplify it otherwise.

Any help or pointing in the right direction is much apprecitated :) Thank you.

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools. You're probably looking for profiling. It's impossible to tell how much "too much for a computer" is without actually testing on target hardware.

Comment: @millimoose Travis J, Josiah Hester, Harry & Eric Brown - It's really unfair to just flag my question because you don't know how to answer it. Just so happen that I DID get my answer thanks to Rich and others. There are people out there that need these answers... just because the question doesn't come prepackaged in the way you want it, you should not flag it... at least not without explaining yourself further as to what's wrong with it. If there are too many answers then please give ONE instead of just flagging - that would be more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Voting is a judgement call, whether you think it's fair or not doesn't matter. You can always make a [meta] post asking for reopen votes if you feel the close was unjustified - the close-reopen system works based on a "dynamic consensus". Also, "too broad" is there for a reason. If you disagree that questions should be closed for that reason in general feel free to argue against that "policy" on meta. In the meantime, I take its existence as a signal that the community as a whole does not welcome very general, unfocused questions, and you admitted your question is very general yourself.

Comment: Yes, I did. I apologize for the unfocused question, yet I think the underlying issue was quite clear. Anyway... no problem. I got my answer. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this app called [Spy-JS](http://spy-js.com/).

It is a tool which allows you to trace your code, and figure out which executions are taking the longest, allowing you to figure out where you need to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

The tool you are searching for is called a "profiler".

The [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) extension for Firefox comes with such a profiler and allows you to measure which parts of your Javascript code take how much time to execute.

Keep in mind that it only measures the execution speed in Firefox. Other browsers might implement certain javascript features more or less efficient, which means that the performance bottlenecks could be in other places when your application is executed in another browser. But more often than not your own code is at fault when a program runs slower than it should.

Comment: Hi - I have Firebug but I cannot find any profiler option. Is it called something different maybe?

Comment: @NoodleHead It's under console -> time measurement